# Can not copy text from QSpinBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qspinbox

I've a legacy code using c++ with Qt. It has many QSpinBoxes.
Strangely not a single QSpinBox allows me to copy text from it and paste in other spinbox. Ctr+C and Ctr+V simply doesn't work. Also, I tried to select the text in QSpinBox and copy with right-click copy option. But the text is not copied and could not be pasted.

In my other PyQt code I can do these copy paste operations without any problem.

Can somebody help me resolve this problem?

I'm running Qt 4.8.6 on Win32(XP).

Comment: It should be some code processing that in your application, you should find it and delete if this is undesired. Try to look for eventFilter and  QEvent::KeyPress

Comment: The initial idea behind that is preventing user pasting wrong value into spin box I guess

Comment: I checked for any KeyPress event override. Also, signals and slots related to the QSpinBoxes. The application is using many spinboxes, none of them allows copy paste.

Comment: If there is an `&` in the names of some of the `QActions` or `QMenu` items, or if `Ctrl+C` is set as an accelerator (shortcut key) for something, it may be trumping your copy paste actions.  Another thing to note, is if you are on a Mac, it would be `Command+C` or `Command+V`.  Have you tried block commenting out large parts of the program to see if there is some other chunk of code causing the behavior?  (Basically finding the minimum amount of code to reproduce the problem?)